# Splitting a single column of data into multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, set, range, offset

So I am pretty new to using VBA in excel. So please bear with my ignorance.

I have a column of depths in meters which correspond to an interval. I want to paste the 4 depths under each interval off to the right. This would be a simple copy and paste, but i wish to automate this. I've tried writing some code in VBA but i am running into errors which likely have to do with my limited understanding of the syntax.

There is likely a far easier way to do this, and I would be all ears.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
            1   2   3
```

1   6129
1   6112
1   6094
1   6077
2   6059
2   6041
2   6024
2   6006
3   5989
3   5971
3   5953
3   5936

```
Sub copyperfs()

Dim i As Long, intervals As Long, j As Long, numperfs As Long

Dim offsetcell As Range, offsetcell_paste As Range
Dim startpos As Range, start_paste As Range

'enter number of perforations per interval
numperfs = 4
'enter number of intervals
intervals = 42

Set startpos = Range("AF3")
Set startpos_paste = Range("AI3")

startpos.Select

For i = 1 To intervals
    startpos.Select
    Set startpos = ActiveCell
    Set offsetcell = ActiveCell.Offset(numperfs, 0)
'copy range of perfs
    Range(startpos & ":" & offsetcell).Copy
'go to area to paste cells
    startpos_paste.Select
    Set startpos_paste = ActiveCell
    Set offsetcell_paste = ActiveCell.Offset(numperfs, 0)
    Range(startpos_paste & ":" & offsetcell_paste).PasteSpecial
'go over to the right 1 column
    startpos_paste = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

'move start postition
    startpos = offsetcell.Offset(1, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use formula to do this, does it need to be VBA?  VBA wise, you could just use `transpose` i believe where a3:e6 is a1:a4 transposed.  So loop the range in steps of 4 transposing each.  `range("b1:e1").Value=application.transpose(range("a1:a4").Value)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub x()

Dim l As Long
Dim l2 As Long

l = 1
l2 = 1

Do Until Range("a" & l).Value = ""

    Range("b" & l2).Resize(1, 4).Value = Application.Transpose(Range("a" & l).Resize(4, 1).Value)

    l = l + 4
    l2 = l2 + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, I don't like those lower case Ls, they look like 1s. Looks like a good answer though.